# SSRS 'Zebra striping' not working as expected

Tags: reporting-services, formatting, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

Why isn't 'ALT' (variable used to determine row colour) being updated (see pic)

Here is the code:

```
Private Alt As Boolean
Private cnt as integer
Function Stripe(ByVal NewRow As Boolean, ByVal OddColor as String, ByVal EvenColor as String) As String
    If NewRow Then 
Alt = Not Alt ' Trip the switch denoting a new row
cnt = cnt + 1
end if
    If Alt Then
        Return OddColor
    Else
        Return EvenColor
    End If
End Function

Function getalt () as boolean
return alt
end function    

function getcnt() as integer
return cnt
end function
```

here is the code that goes in the 'background color'
first column:

```
=Code.Stripe(true, "#E7E7E7", "Transparent")
```

second to N columns:

```
=Code.Stripe(False, "#E7E7E7", "Transparent")
```

n.b. you may need to open the image in another window to see the debug output - I'm showing the values of 'cnt' and 'alt' using getalt & getcnt

[image]

Comment: Can you add the text of the function you used to the question? I don't think I would use `RowNumber(Nothing)` as in the linked example - instead, I would replace `Nothing` with the name of the dataset in double quotes.

Comment: I rewrote the entire question with better samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BGcolor code needs to be this in the first column

=IIF(code.getcnt() Mod 2, "#E7E7E7", "Transparent")  & Code.Stripe(TRUE, "", "")

and this in the 2nd..N columns

=IIF(code.getcnt() Mod 2, "#E7E7E7", "Transparent")  & Code.Stripe(FALSE, "", "")

I'm sure the code can be tidied up :)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're making things too complicated.  You can use [RowNumber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159225%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to achieve alternate background coloring, something like:

> =IIF(RowNumber("YourDataset") Mod 2, "#E7E7E7", "Transparent")

Note that YourDataset can also be the scope if you're using grouping.

Comment: This does not work - here is the error:    "The BackgroundColor expression for the text box 'textbox5' has a scope parameter that is not valid for RunningValue, RowNumber or Previous. The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to the name of a containing group within the Tablix 'matrix1'"

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. What happens if you use RowNumber(Nothing) instead?